# Getting source code from VSS into my workspace - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-sourcesafe

we are getting the Source code (in Eclipse IDE) from VSS , during the execution process its produce an error,

reason - Classpath and Project files was not created,

if we move both Classpath and Projects files into the VSS its working fine during the execution, but its not the right way to move the classpath and projects file into VSS

Let me know the steps to getting the source code from VSS into my Eclipse

Comment: Aren't that files beginning with a period: `.classpath`, `.project`. Typically such files and especially directories are considered "hidden", and some version control systems ignore them (think of `.cvs`). So I would look into the **ignore** settings.

Comment: step 1: without moving (into the VSS) the .classpath and .project and getting the source code from VSS , this time Execution (code running) was failed and Step 2: with Moving the .classpath and .projects into vss the execution was correctly